# 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED Minecraft Mod Coder Pack Error

Tags: java, minecraft

While decompiling MCP 9.18 (Version 1.8.8 of Minecraft) I start the decompilation process and while decompiling it comes up with this error multiple times

I have allocated more ram and such but nothing I have tried has fixed it.

Keep in mind this only happens on MCP 9.18. 9.10 and above works fine from what I have tested.

> == ERRORS FOUND ==
>
> ```
> 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file 'net\minecraft\scoreboard\Scoreboard.ja#'
> ==================
>
> 'runtime\bin\applydiff.exe -p1 -u -i ..\..\temp\temp.patch -d src\minecraft' failed : 1
>
> == ERRORS FOUND ==
>
> 1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file 'net\minecraft\client\gui\GuiPageButton#'
> ==================
>
> 'runtime\bin\applydiff.exe -p1 -u -i ..\..\temp\temp.patch -d src\minecraft' failed : 1
>
> == ERRORS FOUND ==
>
> 4 out of 5 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file 'net\minecraft\world\gen\structure\StructureMine#'
> ==================
>
> 'runtime\bin\applydiff.exe -p1 -u -i ..\..\temp\temp.patch -d src\minecraft' failed : 1'
> ```

Further down it continues on to a mess of characters

> src\minecraft\net\minecraft\client\gui\FontRenderer.java:667: error:
>   unmappable character for encoding Cp1252
>               int lvt_2_1_ = "├Ç├?├é├ê├è├ï├?├ô├ö├ò├Ü├ƒ├ú├╡─ƒ─░─▒┼Æ┼ô┼₧┼ƒ┼┤┼╡┼╛╚ç\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000
>   !\"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\u0000├ç├╝├⌐├ó├ñ├á├Ñ├º├¬├½├¿├»├«├¼├ä├à├ë├ª├å├┤├╢├▓├╗├╣├┐├û├£├╕┬ú├ÿ├ù╞Æ├í├¡├│├║├▒├æ┬¬┬║┬┐┬«┬¼┬╜┬╝┬í┬½┬╗ΓûæΓûÆΓûôΓöéΓöñΓòíΓòóΓòûΓòòΓòúΓòæΓòùΓò?Γò£Γò¢Γö?ΓööΓö┤Γö¼Γö£ΓöÇΓö╝Γò₧ΓòƒΓòÜΓòöΓò⌐ΓòªΓòáΓò?Γò¼ΓòºΓò¿ΓòñΓòÑΓòÖΓòÿΓòÆΓòôΓò½Γò¬ΓöÿΓöîΓûêΓûäΓûîΓû?ΓûÇ╬▒╬▓╬ô╧Ç╬ú╧â╬╝╧ä╬ª╬ÿ╬⌐╬┤Γê₧ΓêàΓêêΓê⌐Γëí┬▒ΓëÑΓëñΓîáΓîí├╖Γëê┬░ΓêÖ┬╖ΓêÜΓ?┐┬▓Γûá\u0000".indexOf(character);
>
> ```
>                                      ^
> src\minecraft\net\minecraft\client\renderer\EntityRenderer.java:1990:
> ```
>
> error: unclosed character literal
>                   GL11.glFogi('ΦòÜ', 'Φò¢');
>                               ^
>
> ```
> src\minecraft\net\minecraft\client\renderer\EntityRenderer.java:1990:
> ```
>
> error: illegal character: '\u2022'
>                       GL11.glFogi('ΦòÜ', 'Φò¢');

```
                              ^
```

I'm running Windows 10 (64 bit), allocated 2gb of ram to fernflower but no matter how many times I have tried to run it it hasn't fixed the issue. This ONLY happens with MCP 9.18.

Here is what I've tried

```
 1. Allocated more RAM
 2. Reinstalling MCP
 3. Reinstalling Minecraft 1.8.8
 4. Updating Java
 5. Restarting PC
```

It DOES generate the eclipse folder which has about 1000 errors so something is definitely broken.

MCPERR.log: https://hastebin.com/ojimijazem.tex
MCP.log: https://b.catgirlsare.sexy/owX3.log

Does anybody know what these errors mean and how I could potentially fix it?

Comment: That's... weird.  You're getting char literals, when you should be getting numbers (the decompile doesn't know the difference, so it assumes large numbers are chars... yea.).  MCP has a process that's supposed to keep that from happening (though I don't know the details).

Comment: I do not understand either why it is **only** mcp 9.18. I can decompile all of the other ones just fine but this one just gives me an error.

Comment: Can you post the log MCP creates?

Comment: Actually, looking at that further, that huge mess of characters is MC's charset.  I'm not sure why that's decompiling that way - normally it creates escapes.  And, the other patches shouldn't be failing, unless your mappings are borked.  You might have broken the config when allocating more ram to fernflower?

Comment: So, question, why are you using MCP and not Forge?

Comment: @Pokechu I only added the 2g part into fernflower and I will post MCP log tomorrow when I get home.

Comment: @Draco18s I'm not necessarily looking to publish this "mod" I am creating and I feel like I have more control with mcp.

Comment: All the control and none of the safeguards.

Comment: @Pokechu22 I have added the logs to the op at the near bottom

Comment: `warn: missing '-Xmx2G', ignored` on the fernflower command.  You put `-Xmx2G` after `-jar`; it needs to be before for it to be passed to java.  It looks like that caused fernflower to stop parsing arguments, meaning it didn't receive any of `-din=1 -rbr=1 -dgs=1 -asc=1 -rsy=1 -iec=1 -jvn=1 -log=WARN`.  I have no clue what any of those do, but I think they're probably important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Pokechu22 Told me what the problem was.

I used -Xmx2G ***AFTER*** -jar Which caused it to ignore important fernflower arguments.

Answer (score 0):

MCP 940 has the error of hunk errors

And it is not possible to use -Xmx2G

There is no actual fix for this we can only wait till owners of mcp

Make a new one!